# Read a valid formated html local file using chrome with tmp extension

Tags: c#, html, google-chrome

I've got a local file with a temporary extension (.tmp) which contains valid HTML code. I would like to allow chrome to read this file as a basic HTML file. 
When i load this file using chrome (e.g: file:///C:/file.tmp), chrome read it as a text file.
I'm using currently list of chromium command: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/  but cannot find which command (if exists?) could let me do what i wish.

This question is not relative to csharp but i'm using a net application to load the file, here is the code:

```
 var url = localFilePathUri; //e.g: file:///C:/file.tmp
 string args = "--kiosk --allow-file-access " + url;
 var test = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", args);
```

I could rename local file to use .html as extension but i would like to know if a more direct way exists?

Thank you!

Comment: I think its easier to get the content of the file and put it into a clean html. You can do this with JS but with php is really easy
http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: I'm remembering that php allows to copy files, in this process you can change the extension to .html and open the file